# Do i need to install again all application in dual-booting OS?

Tags: windows-10

I have some issues regarding dual operating system, recently I have installed dual windows 10 (Same version) with different hard drives, so could anyone guide me that all drivers and applications that I had installed in my previous windows (Same version) will need to install again? i.e all drivers and apps etc?

Comment: Two separate installations = Two systems so yes, you will need to install everything unless you cloned the disk to the another.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to install apps again and if the same Windows 10 license you can only have one disk running at one time. Dual boot on one computer forces this

Comment: Ok, I have one more concern, when I installed second windows and log in to 2nd one my c drive look more fill up with space? I know I have installed the second window to another separate drive? so why show less space and this happen to firs one as weel new hard drive is also show less space when I log in to the first window?

Comment: If the applications are the same, then the system may have done a Feature Update which makes a Windows.old file that can be 20 to 30 GB in size

Comment: Actually, I have not installed second windows onto the same drive so there is no change to create window-es.old folder?

Comment: You would have to look and see how big this folder is and whether you still need it.

Comment: Also make sure you only have one disk installed at one time. If Windows sees its license on another drive it will have issues. You can solve this with two licenses